# How to register HttpClient Handler in Blazor Client?

Tags: c#, blazor, httpclient, blazor-webassembly

I want to preprocess and postprocess all outgoing requests that are going from my Blazor client to Server API. The best solution is to add custom HttpMessageHandler.

**Handler code:**

```
public class NameOfMyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public NameOfMyHandler()
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Process request");
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        Debug.WriteLine("Process response");
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Code in Client->Program.cs->Main:**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<NameOfMyHandler>();
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ThisIsClientCustomName", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<NameOfMyHandler>();
```

But when I try to do so I get an error:

```
An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
```

but as you can see in the code I do specify the `BaseAddress` and I am sure it is correct.

Where is the problem ? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I found out it requires more than adding that handler. And also it is possible to do it with `AddHttpClient` or pure `HttpClient`.

**AddHttpClient example:**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<NameOfMyHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ThisIsClientCustomName", 
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<NameOfMyHandler>();
// Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("ThisIsClientCustomName"));
```

or

**Pure HttpClient**:

```
HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler = new NameOfMyHandler()
{
    InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
};
builder.Services.AddScoped<NameOfMyHandler>(sc => httpMessageHandler);
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
};
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => httpClient);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I used the "Pure HttpClient" option, and I removed the AddScoped for the "NameOfMyHandler" line that was not needed.